# Escape Function in Shell Programming

Tags: bash, shell

Why does the command

```
echo `echo \\z`
```

result in

```
z
```

instead of

```
\z
```

Comment: Which OS ? My result on mac : `echo \z`

Comment: Are you meaning `echo \\z` or `echo echo \\z` ?

Comment: Kubuntu 12.04 GNU bash, Version 4.2.25(1)-release (i686-pc-linux-gnu) gives: `echo \z`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `` `..` `` adds an additional escape level. `$(..)` does not, and is the preferred way of doing command expansion.

Given

```
echo `echo \\z`
```

we can remove a level of escaping and use `$(..)` to get:

```
echo $(echo \z)
```

and unquoted, `\z` is equivalent to `z`, so we end up with:

```
echo $(echo z)
```

Note that the outer echo has nothing to do with this. Backslashes are never treated specially when part of expansion data.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose what you are actually running is:

```
echo `echo \\z`
```

If that's the case, in the inner echo, `\\` was escaped to a `\`, and then in the external echo, `\z` results in "z". Same as if you run

echo \z

Btw, note the use of single commas to prevent escaping

```
echo '\\z'
```

which results in

```
\\z
```

Comment: Did you actually try it, and can you reproduce it? What OS and what bash version?

Comment: @grebneke Sorry, I was a bit too hasty. I updated the answer now

Comment: Your answer is correct - the backticks in the question were not visible at first.

Comment: @grebneke thanks for rechecking it. I've had my share of problems when using the code escaping symbol inside escaped code in stackoverflow :P